# React-query FC cannot be used as a JSX component, missing properties from Element type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, react-query

I'm trying to implement `useQuery` to return the number (.length) of records I have of a given model, in this case, properties.

```
async function fetchProperties(): Promise<Property[]> {
  return axios
    .get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/properties")
    .then((res) => res.data);
}

export default function UsePropertiesCount() {
  return useQuery<Property[], Error, number>("properties", fetchProperties, {
    select: (properties: Property[]) => properties.length,
  });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
'UsePropertiesCount' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'UseQueryResult<number, Error>' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'QueryObserverIdleResult<number, Error>' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': type, props, key
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, since I've followed [this example](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-and-type-script)

Comment: Your `export default` in the file returns a `useQuery` which is not a JSX Element (an HTML element). React cannot render it. If you do not intend to return any JSX element in your file, the extension should be `.ts` instead of `.tsx`.

Answer (score 0):

When I saved the query to a variable and returned it with `result.data` it worked

```
const result = useQuery<Property[], Error, number>(
    "properties",
    fetchProperties,
    {
      select: (properties: Property[]) => properties.length,
    }
  );
  return <>{result.data}</>;
```